# Type aggregation in ElasticSearch (Nest)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

There are 3 types in the Elasticsearch index: type1, type2, type3. 
I need to filter by type(by default filtering value = type1). But also I need to get type aggregations.
But it's impossible because in each query I use filter and there are only objects of filtering type. 
Please, help me to figure out how to do it. Is there only way to use the second query without filter?

Comment: What  do you mean by "type" aggregations? Do you mean terms aggregations? It's not entirely clear what you are asking. Could you explain in more detail, maybe with an example in code or pseudocode?

Comment: it's a problem of using filter and aggregation on the same field

Comment: why do you want to use a filter while retrieving aggregations? can you expand your example and explain what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a use-case for [post-filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html)

> The post_filter is applied to the search hits at the very end of a
>   search request, after aggregations have already been calculated.

```
  {
      "query": {
         "match_all": {}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "typeAggr": {
          "terms": { "field": "type" } 
        }
      },
      "post_filter": { 
        "term": { "type": "type1" }
      }
    }
```

This query will list the docs matching filter (type1) whereas the aggregation will give results irrespective of the filter on `type` field.